# Confusion about 'minimally coupled' and 'massive' Scalar Tensor Theory

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, field-theory, modified-gravity

So if I write down a general action of Scalar Tensor Theory in a Jordan frame as
$$
S = 
\frac{1}{16\pi G_0}\int \left( f_1(\varphi) R
- f_2(\varphi) g^{\alpha \beta} \partial_\alpha \varphi \partial_\beta \varphi
- 2 f_3(\varphi) \right)
\, \sqrt{-g} \, \mathrm{d}^4x \,,
$$
for a bare gravitational constant $G_0$ and arbitrary functions $f_1,f_2$ and $f_3$, when exactly to we talk about a *massive/massles* or *minimal/non-minimal coupled* scalar field $\varphi$?

Am I correct in thinking that massive/massless depends on if the *scalar potential* $f_3$ is zero or not?

And I would guess that we talk about a scalar field coupled to gravity if $f_1$ really depends on $\varphi$? If so, if I make a conformal transformation I can get rid of $f_1$ for the cost of a conformal factor, so is the scalar field in the conformal Einstein frame no longer non-minimally coupled to gravity?

This is all a bit confusing to me and I haven't found a book that clears that all up. Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Massive vs Massless**: This boils down to the following question in perturbation theory. If you expand $\phi=\bar{\phi}+\delta \phi$ and $g_{\mu\nu} = \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} + h_{\mu\nu}$ for some background configuration consisting of a background metric $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$ and scalar $\bar{\phi}$, then is there a quadratic term in the action $\sim (\delta \phi)^2$ with no derivatives? This can be complicated if term like $\sim h \phi$ appears, since you may need to "diagonalize the mass matrix" to determine if there is a mass (similar to how you need to find eigenvalues of the mode matrix when you have coupled harmonic oscillators to find the fundamental frequencies). Generally, when people talk about a "massless" or "massive" scalar field, they have in mind the background (in units where $c=\hbar=1$) $f_1(\bar\phi)=\frac{1}{8\pi G}$ and $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}$; then you will get some condition on the $f$ functions like $f_3''(\bar{\phi})=0$ (although as a warning it's been a while since I've worked this out in detail, so the exact condition in this case might be different due to the kinetic mixing of $\delta \phi$ and $h$ present in the modified Einstein-Hilbert term, although I don't think that *should* affect the mass term).

**Non-minimal coupling**: There are different uses for this phrase, so make sure you understand what the source you are working from means. However, in general, I would say in gravitational theories, nminimal coupling refers to taking the action for some matter field (in this case a scalar field, $\phi$) on Minkowski space, then replacing the Minkowski metric $\eta_{\mu\nu}$ with the dynamical spacetime metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ and any partial derivatives $\partial_\mu$ with covariant derivatives $\nabla_\mu$, **and nothing else**. In particular, no couplings proportional to curvature terms should be introduced. So in the context of your theory, I would say that a non-minimally coupled scalar should involve $f_1(\phi)=\frac{1}{8\pi G}$ (that is, a constant), while $f_2$ and $f_3$ are free to be whatever they want. Note that if $f_1$ is constant, if you're willing to assume $f_2> 0$ everywhere (which you should, otherwise you will run into serious stability problems), then you can do a field redefinition of $\phi$ to set $f_2=\frac{1}{2}$, which is the canonical normalization for the kinetic term.

Comment: I concur with your definition of "minimal coupling" in the gravitational context.